# MongoDB sorting the output alphabetically (after grouping)

Tags: mongodb, sorting

I have the following data:

```
[
  {
    "names": [
      "name1,name2,name3"
    ]
  },
  {
    "names": [
      "name1 , name2 , name3 , name4 , name5 , name6"
    ]
  }
]
```

Which I reduce to a set of unique values by removing whitespace and splitting by commas, using the following query:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      names: {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$names",
          initialValue: [],
          in: {
            $setUnion: [
              {
                $split: [
                  "$$this",
                  ","
                ],
                
              },
              "$$value"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$names"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$a",
      names: {
        $addToSet: {
          $trim: {
            input: "$names",
            chars: " "
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Everything works as you can see here: https://mongoplayground.net/p/nlK5Gmf-gkw
The list of unique values produces, however, I need to sort the results alphabetically and the sorting mechanism added like this:

```
{
    $sort: {
      "a": -1
    }
}
```

, doesn't seem to work.

The result I get is unsorted:

```
[
  {
    "_id": null,
    "names": [
      "name1",
      "name5",
      "name4",
      "name6",
      "name3",
      "name2"
    ]
  }
]
```

Any suggestions?

https://mongoplayground.net/p/nlK5Gmf-gkw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need change the order of stage and operations,

- `$group` by null and use the same process that you used `$reduce` to split string to array and `$map` to remove white space from names using `$trim`
- `$project` to update get unique array from all names using `$reduce` and `$setUnion`
- `$unwind` deconstruct `names` array
- `$sort` by names descending order
- `$group` by null and make array of `names`

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      names: {
        $push: {
          $map: {
            input: {
              $reduce: {
                input: "$names",
                initialValue: [],
                in: { $split: ["$$this", ","] }
              }
            },
            in: { $trim: { input: "$$this" } }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      names: {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$names",
          initialValue: [],
          in: { $setUnion: ["$$this", "$$value"] }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { $unwind: "$names" },
  { $sort: { names: -1 } },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      names: { $push: "$names" }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/cgw1arKVx_b)

Comment: Your playground doesn't seem to work, output is not sorted either, every time I run it, it produces a different sorting... also, can you use my example for alphabetical sorting?

Comment: perfect, that worked like a charm, now let me see how you did this :)

Comment: I've accepted it as an answer, even though on a larger set of data it's extremely slow or timing out with memory issues. My unsorted version did not have this issue, so the slowness is due to sorting (not an issue with your query I think)

Comment: Yes it could be, if you are using mongodb 4.4. then my suggestion is you can try $function operator, might be all operation will handle by single process.